# Apache ProxyPass all requests

Tags: apache, http, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have Proxy Pass somewhat working. I am using it like so

```
ProxyPass     /chorus/   http://localhost:7070/
ProxyPassReverse /chorus/   http://localhost:7070/
```

This chorus folder does not exist and I am accessing through apache port 80 in the browser. Then it redirects to my application running on port 7070 which provides its webpage. The functionality within the webpage does not work though because the javascript starts requesting images and other info as /images/image1.jpg for example or /jsonrpc on apache and isn't going through the proxy. But on port 80 there is no /images because it's part of the :7070 application. If I do like below it will work too, but there are too many folders, I need a way to set everything returned from 7070 to be processed by apache as http:// localhost:7070/image/...

```
ProxyPass /jsonrpc   http://localhost:7070/jsonrpc
ProxyPass /image  http://localhost:7070/image
```

Basically the page for the app loads but the content does not, the app is requesting /jsonrpc which looks something like this (proxied version)

```
Remote Address:192.168.1.150:80
Request URL:http://192.168.1.150/jsonrpc?tm=1419196786193
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

When in the app directly without proxy it looks like this

```
Remote Address:192.168.1.150:7070
Request URL:http://192.168.1.150:7070/jsonrpc?tm=1419196894248
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not really something you can fix within the Proxy module, other than by spelling out all possible paths, which you want to avoid; your alternatives are:

- a. change the application and make it proxy aware so that

  - a1. it produces paths by prefixing it with a configured path
  - a2. interprets something like a `X-Forwarded-Path` header
  - a3. uses the HTML base tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp
- b. change the proxy so that your app lives on it's own vhost e.g. chorus.example.org

Comment: I see, I have no problem making a vhost for this. I did not develop the app so this is the easiest option for me. Thanks! I will try and report back. Do you have an example of how I could do that?